# Problems with $near in MongoDB without using $maxDistance

Tags: mongodb

Currently we have big trouble with the `$near` operation in `MongoDB 3.2.9`.

The problem is that there is an endless load - until timeout - when creating the cursor. This problem just causes when we're not using `$maxDistance` - which in our case is important not to use.

This is our collection:

**Locations**

Around 2.000.000 Documents with the GeoJSON property "geometry" which is also indexed.

Beside geometry there is another index called "category".

In our special case our query now looks like this:

```
Locations.find({
  category: 'ABC',
  geometry: { 
    '$near': { 
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ 13.357315063476564, 52.53167855932515 ]
      }
    } 
  } 
}, {
  limit: 10
});
```

This query will result in an **timeout**.

To solve this we need to add the `$maxDistance` operation and it will work fine (if the value of the $maxDistance is not too high) But in our case a `$maxDistance` is very bad because it doesn't matter if 1 location has a huge distance to another one. For example its okay when the first found location is in Norway and the second somewhere in Australia.

**Another information:**

This problem just causes when there are **LESS** then the limit of results. In our example above there are 8 Locations with this category in our database. If we would do the same query with 10 oder more locations it will take around a few milliseconds.

Just to sum this up:

```
// Does not work. Ends up in an timeout
Locations.find({
  category: 'ABC', // has 9 locations
  geometry: { 
    '$near': { 
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ 13.357315063476564, 52.53167855932515 ]
      }
    } 
  } 
}, {
  limit: 10
});

// Works fine because of the $maxDistance - but in our case a $maxDistance is very BAD and needed to be prevented!
Locations.find({
  category: 'ABC', // has 9 locations
  geometry: { 
    '$near': { 
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ 13.357315063476564, 52.53167855932515 ]
      }
    },
    '$maxDistance': 5000 // If this value is too high - like the maxDistance is "the whole world" the query would also end up in an timeout 
  } 
}, {
  limit: 10
});

// Works fine because >= 10 items
Locations.find({
  category: 'DEF', // has 10 locations
  geometry: { 
    '$near': { 
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ 13.357315063476564, 52.53167855932515 ]
      }
    } 
  } 
}, {
  limit: 10
});
```

We are using **MongoDB 3.2.9**

**Additional Info**

This problem has nothing to do with the fact that we are using MongoDB in nodeJS. We are also using RoboMongo and when executing this query the same problem causes: a timeout!

Comment: Perhaps you need to use `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` for  the value of `$maxDistance`. Works perfectly for me with 2000002 documents

Comment: Sadly this does not work for us. With this the query also ends up in an timeout.

Comment: What is the Mongo driver you are using?

Comment: The problem happens in RoboMongo (dont know what kind of driver they are using ?) and in our nodeJS Application.

Comment: I think RoboMongo does not use a driver, it seems that it is just a GUI for Mongo Shell. I created 2 millions documents having the same fields with random values as your and ran the `find` operation. It took about ~50s to finish, not sure why it happens to you

Comment: 50s or 50ms ? I mean 50s is quite a lot and should not happen

Comment: it was 50 seconds, it makes sense actually. geo search is a very cpu intensive task. Plus we do not provide the `$maxDistance` value that makes Mongo search "all over the world"

Comment: Then you have the same issue like us. Our document is also other data and so the collection is huge (in size). I think our timeout result is also after around a Minute. I thought because we have indexes mongoDb will be able to finish this query much way faster - also it seems that mongodb is ignoring that the other indexed field (category) has only 9 items and even then mongo is not stopping the query after ot has found all 9 items. There must be something wrong!

Comment: hmm I think I know the problem, did you create a `single field index` or a `compound index`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129422/discussion-between-timo-rutten-and-khang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a collection as you have containing 2 million documents with random data, prepared the indexes for `category` and `geometry` fields. When I went on testing this collection, I hit on the same problem as you.

It took about 50 seconds without `$maxDistance` value. At first it seemed reasonable because without `$maxDistance` Mongo have to search "all over the world" for the result. But then I checked the [`.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.explain/) result of the query and realized it did not use indexes at all, there was no stage [`IXSCAN`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/explain-results/#collection-scan-vs-index-use) (this was `BasicCursor` in older version of Mongo) in the query. So the problem is clear, I created the indexes wrongly, so did you.

The indexes you (me too) created is [Single Field Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-single/) which only helps when searching by a single field. In this case, you search by two fields so you need to use [Compound Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound). use this command to create the compound index which can be used in the search:

```
db.collection({category: 1, geometry: '2dsphere'});
```

I did that and the result was amazing, the time reduced from 50 seconds to a few hundred milliseconds.